# Why is this button cut off?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In the following XAML code the button text is half missing. I can change the `Margin` property and it becomes obvious that after 250px the content is hidden. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

```
<Window x:Class="InnerInterface.InventoryManagement" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="someWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Name="buttonReturnToMainMenu" Content="someButton" Margin="200,0" Width="125" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a horizontal margin of 200, and a button width of 125, which means the total width needed to show the control properly is about 525.

You also have `HorizontalAlignment=Left"` on your `DockPanel`, which means it will draw the content at whatever width it needs and align it to the left side of the screen instead of stretching it to fill all available space. This means it is blocking out a space of 200 on either side of the control, and drawing the button in the remaining space. If this remaining space is less than 125, the image will be cropped.

If you switch to `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, then it will draw the control first (with margins), then stretch it's size so it fits all available space, so the entire control gets resized rather than cropped.

You might be interested in reading [this MSDN article on Alignment, Margins, and Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) in WPF.

**Edit**

If you want **only** the `Left` margin to be 200, then use `Margin="200,0,0,0"`. Using `Margin="200,0"` means that both the left and the right Margins will be 200.

Comment: Thanks. Even adding `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` to the button doesn't help. In fact, that was already in my working code but I removed it from the SO question to reduce it to the simplest case. I can also move the button all the way to the left with `Margin` and the whole button shows. Furthermore, other (wider) controls (TextBoxes) in the same place do show their entire width.

Comment: @dotancohen Re-read the 3rd paragraph: If you switch to `HorizontalAlignement="Stretch"` on your `DockPanel`, then it will draw the control first and resize it horizontally to fit your available space, instead of cropping it.

Comment: Thanks, Rachel. I did try adding `HorizontalAlignement="Stretch"` to the `DockPanel`, unfortunately that was not the issue and did not solve the problem. It turns out that the problem was that the `Margin` property was set for both sides, changing it to the left only resolved the issue, as you mention in the edit. I do appreciate your help and follow up!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about your exact problem, but maybe this should help:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
            <Button Name="buttonReturnToMainMenu" Content="someButton" Width="125"  />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do need to move the button over 200 pixels.

Comment: @dotancohen - You say you need to move the button over 200 pixels, but are you also intending on putting a 200 margin on the right side too? Or should you be using `"200, 0, 0, 0"` as your margin?

Comment: Mark, it looks like you and I posted the answer together, and Rachel came to the same conclusion just a few minutes later. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it, as you were the first poster to mention it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rachel - Rachel's got the concept covered in her post and it's got far more detail including WHY the margins are wrong and How they are being calculated than I am inclined to write. I vote to mark hers as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the button `Margin` is set as:

```
Margin="200,0"
```

It should be set as:

```
Margin="200,0,0,0"
```

This eliminates the margin on the right side and allows the whole button to show.

Comment: Actually you were a few minutes off